# Connecting Spark code from web application

Tags: scala, web-applications, apache-spark, bigdata

Can some one please let me know how to connect to Spark application from a web application. The Spark code whatever we are having is on Scala and we want to access the code from web application. If we can provide a small code snippet that will be helpful.

Comment: Could you elaborate the question with more detail? What do you mean by connect? Do you want to execute the Spark application from your web application?

Comment: Yes exactly, from web application I want to execute Spark code. Also the result want to reflect in the web application. Say for example I want to execute equivalent of a small sql (which is Spark code written in Scala) from my web application and also want to show the result in the web application.

Comment: This will help you - https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: Maybe this one also - http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Calling-spark-from-a-java-web-application-td20007.html

Comment: does the above links help?

Comment: Yes, I will try to create a simple web application using the help of those links. If you have any small ready code, request you to please share

Comment: No, i don't have any..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment section, try the following approaches,

[spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)

spark-jobserver provides a RESTful interface for submitting and managing Apache Spark jobs, jars, and job contexts.

[Approach mentioned by Jamal in spark-user-list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Calling-spark-from-a-java-web-application-td20007.html)

1) In the tomcat's classpath, add the spark distribution jar for spark code to be available at runtime

2) In the Web application project, add the spark distribution jar in the classpath ( Could be Java / Web project).

3) Setup the FAIR scheduling mode, which would help send parallel requests from web application to the spark cluster.

4) In the application startup, initialize the connection to the spark cluster. This is composed of creating the JavaSparkContext and making it available throughout the web application, in case this needs to be the only Driver Program required by the web application.

5) Using the JavaSpark Context, Create RDD's and make them available globally to the web application code.

6) invoke transformation / actions as required.